# Python: Google Contacts API only retrieving 3 contacts

Tags: python, google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api, gdata-python-client

I am new to Python and to the Google APIs.

I have the following code from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en:

```
def PrintAllContacts(gd_client):
  feed = gd_client.GetContacts()
  for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
    print '\n%s %s' % (i+1, entry.name.full_name.text)
    if entry.content:
      print '    %s' % (entry.content.text)
    # Display the primary email address for the contact.
    for email in entry.email:
      if email.primary and email.primary == 'true':
        print '    %s' % (email.address)
    # Show the contact groups that this contact is a member of.
    for group in entry.group_membership_info:
      print '    Member of group: %s' % (group.href)
    # Display extended properties.
    for extended_property in entry.extended_property:
      if extended_property.value:
        value = extended_property.value
      else:
        value = extended_property.GetXmlBlob()
      print '    Extended Property - %s: %s' % (extended_property.name, value)
```

This is only returning 3 contacts out of c. 850. Any thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def PrintAllContacts(gc):
    max_results = 20000
    start_index = 1
    query = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsQuery()
    query.max_results = max_results
    query.start_index = start_index
    feed = gc.GetContacts(q=query)
    print len(feed.entry)
    for e in feed.entry:
        print e.name
        for email in e.email:
            print email.address
```

Useful link: https://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/pydocs/gdata.contacts.data.html#ContactEntry